# regex match multiple lines or another solution?

Tags: java, regex, logging

I need to go through log4j logs and extract all the errors, including the multiple lines they may generate for the current day.

```
2012-10-04 # 11:09:00 #  ERROR # org.apache.struts2.components.ActionComponent  # Could not execute action: //application
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 9, Size: 9
    at java.util.ArrayList.RangeCheck(ArrayList.java:547)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:322)
    at com.cisco.smo.actions.SmoTMSLicensesAction.populateTMSConfigAndPeakData(SmoTMSLicensesAction.java:153)
    at com.cisco.smo.actions.SmoTMSLicensesAction.populateTmsData(SmoTMSLicensesAction.java:55)
    at com.cisco.smo.actions.SmoTMSLicensesAction.execute(SmoTMSLicensesAction.java:41)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:453)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:292)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:255)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:256)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:176)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:265)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:211)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:211)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:190)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:75)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:90)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:243)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:145)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:176)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:192)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:187)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
    at org.apache.struts2.components.ActionComponent.executeAction(ActionComponent.java:293)
    at org.apache.struts2.components.ActionComponent.end(ActionComponent.java:175)
    at org.apache.struts2.views.jsp.ComponentTagSupport.doEndTag(ComponentTagSupport.java:42)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.welcome_jsp._jspx_meth_s_005faction_005f0(welcome_jsp.java:619)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.welcome_jsp._jspService(welcome_jsp.java:160)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:690)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:599)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:536)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:954)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doInclude(PageContextImpl.java:684)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.include(PageContextImpl.java:678)
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.include(JspTilesRequestContext.java:80)
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.dispatch(JspTilesRequestContext.java:73)
    at org.apache.tiles.context.TilesRequestContextWrapper.dispatch(TilesRequestContextWrapper.java:72)
    at org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesRequestContext.dispatch(StrutsTilesRequestContext.java:88)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:283)
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.render(InsertAttributeTag.java:140)
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.render(InsertAttributeTag.java:117)
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.RenderTagSupport.execute(RenderTagSupport.java:154)
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.RoleSecurityTagSupport.doEndTag(RoleSecurityTagSupport.java:75)
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.ContainerTagSupport.doEndTag(ContainerTagSupport.java:80)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.common.baseLayout_jsp._jspx_meth_tiles_005finsertAttribute_005f2(baseLayout_jsp.java:221)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.common.baseLayout_jsp._jspService(baseLayout_jsp.java:131)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:690)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:477)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:402)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:329)
    at org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.forward(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:198)
    at org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.dispatch(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:179)
    at org.apache.tiles.context.TilesRequestContextWrapper.dispatch(TilesRequestContextWrapper.java:72)
    at org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesRequestContext.dispatch(StrutsTilesRequestContext.java:88)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:606)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:246)
    at org.apache.struts2.views.tiles.TilesResult.doExecute(TilesResult.java:105)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.StrutsResultSupport.execute(StrutsResultSupport.java:186)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.executeResult(DefaultActionInvocation.java:374)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:278)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:256)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:176)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:265)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:211)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:211)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:190)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:75)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:90)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:243)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:145)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:176)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:192)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:187)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:510)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:434)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1001)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
 2012-10-04 # 11:09:00 #  INFO  # default.hello  # Started Application
```

I don't want to include the last line in the resulting string but I have included it above to indicate where the regex should stop matching.

I started to write a regex, but I don't really know enough to work out why it's wrong...

```
(2012-10-04)\s#\s[.+]\s#\s\sERROR\s#\s[.+]\s\s#\s[.+](19|20)\d\d[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])
```

I'm not sure Regex is the most efficient way to do this either. I am writing this in Java, if anyone has any other ideas...

Answer (score 3):

This will get you close enough:

`\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s+?#\s+?\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\s+?#\s+?ERROR.+?(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}|$)`

Tested with [regexpal](http://www.regexpal.com)

Which in JAVA LAND is

`String regex = "(\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}\\s+?#\\s+?\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}\\s+?#\\s+?ERROR)(.+?)(\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}|$)";`

And have Pattern.DOTALL

Here is my tester:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("src/error.log")));
        String temp;
        String result = "";
        while((temp = in.readLine()) !=null) {
            result += temp;
            result += "\n";
        }
        in.close();

        String regex = "(\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}\\s+?#\\s+?\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}\\s+?#\\s+?ERROR)(.+?)(\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}|$)";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.DOTALL);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(result);

        while(m.find()) {
            System.out.println("***************** MATCHED****************");
            System.out.println(m.group(1) + m.group(2));
            System.out.println("****************************************");
        }

    }
```

Comment: Trying out this method and using the string `(\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}.*ERROR)(.*?)\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}` returns no matches. What is wrong? I checked with regexPal and it is fine.

Comment: The only input I have to test was what you provided. I put that on a file named `error.log` and I ran it in the main method I provided and It worked for me.

Comment: It does work with that example, but I can't work out why it doesn't when the logs has more events. For example if I copy the INFO line from the bottom to the top, that is included in the match.

Comment: @user1628194 I edited my answer to reflect the new and improved REGEX

Answer (score 2):

```
.*ERROR.*(\n.*(\n\s*at.*)+)?
```

An explanation:

```
.*ERROR.*
```

Capture any line with ERROR in it.

```
(\n.* ...)?
```

Optionally capture another line, followed by...

```
(\n\s*at.*)+
```

Capture at least one line that starts with at.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to code a java program to parse the log file and obtain the errors. Make sure you are using the flags DOTALL and MULTILINE. I also think that your regular expresion will extract the last line in the sample input.

This would be my (untested) solution:

`Pattern.compile("^.*?(?=ERROR).+$(?=.+?INFO)", Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOT_ALL)`

**Edit**
`$(?=.+?INFO)` instead of `$.*?(?=INFO)` to really exclude the last line

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume that when you read this in to compare against your regex, it is being read by some buffer that can read the whole document at a time. If this is the case, the regex is pretty simple

```
regex = "^[\\d]{4}-[\\d]{2}-[\\d]{2}.*?[\\d]{4}-[\\d]{2}-[\\d]{2}"
```

^ - Start of line
[\d]{4}-[\d]{2}-[\d]{2} - Match a date of format YYYY-MM-DD or YYYY-DD-MM
.*? - Reluctant quantifier to grab everything until the next part of the pattern is matched
[\d]{4}-[\d]{2}-[\d]{2} - Match a date of format YYYY-MM-DD or YYYY-DD-MM

By Using the reluctant quantifier you ensure that you only get one complete error in your match. This will grab the date portion of the next error. You can cut this out because you know exactly how long the matching portion is (10 characters).